# Meteor: How to create reactive tree structure from a collection

Tags: tree, meteor

I am using the most recent meteor version, and this is a local deployment.
I have a collection (Folders) that contains a tree structure, in which children nodes have parent node id as an attribute. I'd like to display the tree in a UI tree widget. I've studied the recursive template topics, however, I have a hard time to get children nodes displayed. Here are the relevant template and code.

```
<template name="sideTreeTemplate">
  <div id="tree" style="height: 200px">
    <h2 class="panel">My Data</h2>
    <ul id="treeData" style="display: none;">
      {{#each treeItems }}
        {{> treeNodeTemplate}}
      {{/each }}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<template name="treeNodeTemplate" >
  <li id="{{id}}" title="{{name}}" class="{{type}}">
    {{name}}
    {{#if hasChildren}}
      <ul>
        {{#each children}}
          {{> treeNodeTemplate}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/if}}
  </li>
</template>
```

The client.js code:

```
Template.sideTreeTemplate.treeItems = function() {

  var items = Folders.find({"parent" : null});
  console.log("treeItems length=" + items.count());
  items.forEach(function(item){
    item.newAtt = "Item";
    getChildren(item);
  }); 
  return items;

};


var getChildren = function(parent) {
  console.log("sidetree.getChildren called");
  var items = Folders.find({"parent" : parent._id});
  if (items.count() > 0) {
    parent.hasChildren = true;
    parent.children = items;
    console.log(
        "children count for folder " + parent.name +
        "=" + items.count() + ",
        hasChildren=" + parent.hasChildren
    );
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      getChildren(item);
    });
  }
};
```

The top level of the tree shows up fine, and is reactive, but none of the children are shown, even though the `getChildren` function is called for nodes with children.
My suspicion is that the server sync actually removed the dynamically added properties (i.e. `hasChildren`, `children`) for each node.
In this case, how can I make reactive tree working? Or maybe it is something else wrong with my implementation?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pro tip: don't use tabs in code, and especially don't paste them here. They can break everything.

Comment: Pro tip: If you want to use collection elements as an array, you need to use `fetch` in addition to `find`, like so: `var items = Folders.find({parent: parent._id}).fetch();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple way is not to add children objects as properties of the parent object. Instead, use a helper:

```
Template.treeNodeTemplate.hasChildren = function() {
  return Folders.find({parent: this._id}).count() > 0;
};

Template.treeNodeTemplate.children = function() {
  return Folders.find({parent: this._id});
};
```

Comment: Thanks Hubert. This is working! Now I just need to figure out how to keep the tree state (open/close nodes) after reactivity. BTW, what do you mean by not using "TAB"? Does it break anything?